# Setup Wizard Permission Error on Activation (403)

Tags: plugins

Have a bit of a problem (since no one else has it, seems to be specific to me!:)). I have a WordPress plugin that works fine. So I added a setup wizard to it. Added the relevant steps(files) to a subfolder within the plugin folder (folder/files permissions are correct and tried with 777 also).
On activation I get: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page. When I remove the setup wizard, the plugin gets activated and there are no problems.

There are no errors in WordPress logs (switched on from wp-config.php). Only error I get is in apache access logs - 403.

Following are the relevant snippets:

From the main file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ob_flush();

    // Add an activation hook
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate_setup_wizard');

function my_plugin_activate_setup_wizard() {
     $capability = 'manage_options';
    // Redirect the user to the first step of the setup wizard
    wp_safe_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=my-plugin-setup-wizard/step1.php&step=1'));
    exit;
}
```

Step 1. of the wizard:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Displays the first step of My Plugin Setup Wizard.
 */

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

function my_plugin_activate_setup_wizard_step1() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- Progress Indicator -->
        <div class="setup-wizard-progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 25%;"></div>
        </div>

        <h1 class="h4 card-header bg-white border-bottom-0 pt-4 pb-1">
            <?php esc_html_e('Welcome to My Plugin Setup Wizard!', 'my-plugin-wp'); ?>
        </h1>

        <div class="card-body text-muted">
            <p><?php esc_html_e('Thank you for choosing My Plugin - The WordPress Plugin', 'my-plugin-wp'); ?></p>
            <hr class="mt-4 pt-3 pb-0" />
            <p class="small"><?php echo wp_kses_post(__('This quick setup wizard will help you configure the basic settings. It’s completely optional and shouldn’t take longer than five minutes.', 'my-plugin-wp')); ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer mb-0 bg-white gp-setup-actions step border-top-0">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($next_url); ?>" class="btn btn-primary button-next"><?php esc_html_e("Let's get started!", 'my-plugin-wp'); ?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin.php?page=my-plugin-settings-page')); ?>" class="btn btn-secondary d-block mt-2"><?php esc_html_e('Cancel', 'my-plugin-wp'); ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Hook this step to your setup wizard
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_plugin_setup_wizard_step1');
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: 403 on the POST to activate the plugin or 403 on your admin?wizard page?

Comment: You could add error_log() trace to the plugin activation code to see if you're getting that far, I'd also modify wp_die() to write out the error and stack trace to error_log() so you can see where this is getting triggered from: there are a lot of 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page' in the admin site, although most are for multisites.

Comment: Also if you've got any security plugins it might be worth looking at them or turning them off temporarily in case they're blocking this. (I also suspect that's not the right way to start a setup wizard, but I wouldn't know how it's supposed to be done.)

Comment: There are no security plugins. There's a 302 on the GET activate plugin call and 403 on the GET setup wizard call. I am adding the logging code I have on top of the plugin.

Comment: I'd debug admin.php then. It looks like the way it handles these pages varies depending on whether you've registered [a plugin page hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_page_hook/) or not, so I'd add trace to the $plugin_page blocks to see how the decisions are being made.

Comment: Debug admin.php.. wow.. i really do create special problems for myself. Thanks a lot :) Will update.

Comment: ‍♀️ It's a relatively simple file. You just to see the flow through it and the value of a few variables e.g. $plugin_page. Some well-placed error_log()s would do.